# Using JSON instead of text within a PHP array

Tags: php, json

I have the following in my PHP to control access to a page:

```
<?php
    $array = array(
                   'Joe User',
                   'Tom Coffee',
                   'Edith McBurger',
                   'Dan Theman'
    );
    if (in_array($_SESSION['user_name'], $array)) {
    echo '<a href="page2link.php">Link Page</a><br>';
    }

?>
```

It works fine but I'd rather edit a JSON or other small text file instead of editing the whole page just to alter this list.

How do I write this so the list of names is in an external file and my PHP refers to that file?

Comment: use file_get_contents to get the file content with JSON data and use json_decode($fileData, true) to get the data in array. Then use can use in_array to check the $_SESSION as you are doin git now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a .txt file, write one name on separate lines. Then use `file` function to open the file. `file()` creates an array base on each line. Then you can use the rest of your snippet to authenticate.

auth.txt

```
Joe User
Tom Coffee
Edith McBurger
Dan Theman
```

auth.php

```
<?php
    $array = file('auth.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
    if (in_array($_SESSION['user_name'], $array))
    {
        echo '<a href="page2link.php">Link Page</a><br>';
    }
?>
```

- You can use `fopen('auth.txt', "a+")` and `fwrite()` to dynamically write on file later, too.

Answer (score 1):

you can write an JSON file and then just `json_decode` it like this:

your text file:

{

"name":"idan"

}

your php code//

```
<?php

$string = file_get_contents("/your file location");
$json = json_decode($string,true);

echo  $json['name']; //and it will output the value "idan"
```

Comment: echo  $json['key']; is going to give warning for undefined index

Comment: json file works ny key and value - by 'key' its means the json key.